# how to call a function from another function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, function

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Load City by State
    $('#billing_state_id').live('change', function() {
       //do something
    });   
    $('#click_me').live('click', function() {
       //do something
       //need to recall $('#billing_state_id').live('change', function() { but how?
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Load City by State working fine but i don't know whether it's possible or not to call it within another function like `$('#click_me').live('click', function()`.

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, use `on` (check the manual page on it, it's very descriptive. Moreover, jQuery is just JavaScript... you call a function just like you would at any other point with JS

Comment: I suggest you to use on() function against live(). Since live is deprecated.

Comment: Well, I have decided to restore my answer. Indeed, I don't know why I should be fairplay while others aren't. Furthermore, there are too many downvotes on this question and I don't see any good reason for that.

Comment: I dont know why it's downvote, I upvoted it since there are no good reason to downvote this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you don't want to rebind the event, but call the handler.

You can use `trigger()` to trigger events:

```
$('#billing_state_id').trigger('change');
```

If your handler doesn't rely on the event context and you don't want to trigger other handlers for the event, you could also name the function:

```
function someFunction() {
    //do stuff
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Load City by State
    $('#billing_state_id').live('change', someFunction);   
    $('#click_me').live('click', function() {
       //do something
       someFunction();
    });
  });
```

Also note that `live()` is deprecated, `on()` is the new hotness.

Comment: The better approach is to just make the function named and not anonymous. This will also trigger all other handlers attached to the event.

Comment: That depends on intent. maybe it needs to trigger other handlers attached to the event.

Comment: That's a possibility, but it doesn't seem like what OP is trying to do from his description in the question.

Comment: thanks for your quick help. highly appreciated. its what i am looking for. works for me accurately. THANKS :)

Comment: not exactly what i wanted but helped somehow :) upvoted

Answer (score 2):

wrap you shared code into another function:

```
<script>
  function myFun () {
      //do something
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    //Load City by State
    $(document).on('change', '#billing_state_id', function() {
       myFun ();
    });   
    $(document).on('click', '#click_me', function() {
       //do something
       myFun();
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the function with another function? You can just do `click`, myFun);` also note, `.live` is deprecated.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: it's cleaner design. expressly calling an event handler (instead of waiting for events to be dispatched to it) strongly hints at some functionality beyond processing user interaction ('business logic', if you wish to say so) and independent of the semantics of the event. this code portion should thus be be factored out, just imagine later additions of more processing to the 'change' event handler which _is_ idiosyncratic to this event. directly calling the handler from other code portions would break the application in a way hard to detect.

Comment: I think you mixed up what I was trying to sayI did not mean you should use `.click()` or `.change()` to trigger the event manually (See my comment on the other answeR). What I was talking about is writing `myFun` instead of `function(){ myFun()}` since `myFun` is _already_ a function and you're wrapping it in another (anonymous function expression) for a reason that's beyond me :) The second thing I said is that `.live` is deprecated (Since jQuery 1.7 if I recall correctly) and should not be used in new code. `.on` should be preferred to it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: the argument still holds: even if you use a named function, it still is the event handling function - it unites event ui logic and business logic unless separated into different functions. thanks for your advice on the deprecated api call, i have  changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: _what_ "Business Logic" - You're querying your _own_ document, you have query selectors and you listen to view change for executing business logic without any separation. That's the broken 'jQuery way' (people using jQuery for page management and not things like scraping) - the problem in developing an application like this is a lot more inherent than wrapping a function in an excess function expression (which I still don't understand what it accomplish in this case). It's amusing to talk about _proper_ SoC in such a problematic design to begin with.

Comment: Not to mention, we're discussing this over "how to call a function from another function in Jquery" which indicates OP doesn't understand what jQuery is (library), or what JS is (language).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: you assume the functionaliy of the change handler to be a proper subset of that of the click handler and to stay this way for the application's lifetime. while your assumption may be correct, you'll have lots of fun rectifying the code if it doesn't. i would naturally expect much more (and more complex) processing to occur upon a click than upon a change, in particular if the click occurs on a different element.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: i can't really subscribe to your view that the title implies the OP cannot tell a library from the core language (he probably must, if he has authored the statement to load it, right?). i do concur however that this discussion is probably far beyond the OP's needs and the scope of his js code, especially considering the OPs comments on other answers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36481/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-collapsar)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you want something like this:

```
$(window).resize(resize=function resize(){ some code...}
```

Now u can call resize() within some other nested functions:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ resize();}
```