# Callback function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to run `helloWorld()` after execution of `dragTrack()` function. But `helloWorld` is not being called after `dragTrack`.

```
dragTrack(function(){
    helloWorld();
});

function dragTrack() {
    alert('first');
}

function helloWorld() {
    alert('second');
}
```

Comment: dragTrack accepts no parameters ?

Comment: You should first research and than ask questions ,,, refer these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514504/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-function-in-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a function as argument, but `dragTrack` need to be changed to accept the callback and to invoke it

```js
dragTrack(helloWorld);

function dragTrack(callback) {
  alert('first');
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
}

function helloWorld() {
  alert('second');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing helloWorld() as an argument in your dragTrack() call, but you aren't processing it. Your dragTrack function needs a callback Parameter, so you can use your helloWorld() function as an Argument.